# right way of appending a child array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a right way of appending a child array in PHP. If I had an array like this:

```
$arr = [
  'id' => 2,
  'anotherArr' => [
      'id' => 2.1
   ]
];
```

So far I've this:

```
$arr['anotherArr'][] = "'Name' => 'Sam'";
```

perhaps it's not legit. Could you tell a right way? Thanks

Comment: imagine the level of  search you did for this problem

Comment: yeah, i know, sometimes things are just right there, but you're just so overwhelmed

Comment: take multiple breaks, clear your mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had it almost right.

`$arr['anotherArr']['Name'] = 'Sam';`